# What is the best practice for periodic programs in docker?

Tags: docker

I have a program in a docker container that gathers statistics. This data is written to a volume, and the actual reporting on that data is done in another container. The containers themselves contain no persistent data.

The program that gathers statistics needs to run periodically. Is it better to run the container from cron or run cron inside the container to run my program?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally start a cointainer from a cron and have the process exit once it is done. A container should run only one process in the foreground, using crons within the container feels a little hacky.

Comment: Both ways feels a bit hacky. By moving the cron schedule outside of the container, then my app feels less "contained". But having cron inside the container also breaks the one-process goal as you mention.

Comment: I do not find the cron as hacky. It reminds me of jobs in kubernetes, they perform essentially the same function (run until completion).